# I was trying to give myself a role on Discord using Python 3.9 but it shows me an error

Tags: python, discord

I was trying to give myself a role on Discord using Python 3.9 and a bot but it shows me an error.

The code:

```py
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import json
import os
import time

bot = Bot("!")

@bot.command(aliases=['m'])
async def emute(ctx,member : discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    muted_role = ctx.guild.get_role(ROLE ID)

    await member.add_roles(muted_role)

bot.run('TOKEN HERE')
```

---

The error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: member is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Tip for next time you have a question: post the full error traceback for easier debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you running this command? It should be run as `!m @your_username` or the equivalent(ID, username, nick, etc). [Source](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters)

Comment: Thank you, I've tried with `@my_username` and it worked.